# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Multiple build operations failed. Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I recently discovered react-native, so I decided to learn more about this framework. So I created several small projects which worked very well. However, after creating one of them, which caused me a lot of trouble because of the use of react-navigation, I can't run any newly created project. Running an old project with `run-android` is no problem, but if I create a new project without changing anything, I get the following error.

```
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
      Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
      Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
   > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
   > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
   > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
      Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
      Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
   > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
   > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
   > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s

    at makeError (C:\Users\arsen\OneDrive\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\arsen\OneDrive\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\arsen\OneDrive\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\arsen\OneDrive\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have tried a number of  solutions like `./gradlew clean` but when I then try to build my project, I get the same error again.
Ask me if you need any additional information.
I'd appreciate any help as I've been stuck for a few days now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A student of mine had this problem. He was logged into the computer as a domain user. We had him log in as a local user and the problem went away. Seems that some daemon process doesn't have exactly the same perms as the user.

Answer (score 0):

delete .gradle folder in home directory, if on windows (C:\Users\yourname\.gradle), then run

```
yarn android
```

or

```
npx react-native start
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It was an old question so I didn't remember how I solved it, but I think it was something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error due to this
"observed package id 'platform tools' in inconsistent location ......."
to remove this kind of error , go to your sdk file location eg . "C:\User\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" and after going to this location, ou will se perform tools , perform tools 1, perform tools 2 ....., so remove the files which dont contain adb, fastboot etc and rename the file with this name perform tools .
It worked in my case